# Jquery .one is not working on ajax loaded element

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to use jQuery.one on ajax loaded element. It is working if element is loaded already but not when element is being loaded using ajax.

Here is what I am trying to do.

```
$("#selector").one('mouseenter', selMouseEnter);

function selMouseEnter() {
Some code....
}
```

Thx in advance.
Shashi

EDIT:

```
$(".pitem").on('mouseenter', selMouseEnter);

$(".pitem").mouseleave(function(){
    jQuery(this).find(".tooltip").remove();
    $(".pitem").on('mouseenter', selMouseEnter);
});

function selMouseEnter () {
    jQuery(this).find(".tooltip").remove();
        var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('myprize', '');
    var myObj = jQuery('#Py').data('myprize' + id);
    if(myObj) {
        Some code that is opening tooltip having buttons....
    }
}
```

Now conflict is when I click on button in tooltip it is calling mouseenter event again and not the one specific to the button.

Note: #PY comes using ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it is dynamically loaded element you need to use [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or [livequery()](http://brandonaaron.net/code/livequery/docs). Refer links for more info - Use appropriate method depending upon your jquery version

Answer (score 1):

You would have to run your code AFTER the element is put in the page because you are using the static form of `.one()` which requires the element to exist at the time you run the code.

In jQuery 1.7+, you could use the delegated version of `.one()` like this and it would respond to the first mouseenter on the `#selector` object whenever it is added to the page:

```
$(document).one('mouseenter', "#selector", selMouseEnter);
```

Ideally, you would replace `document` with a static parent object of `#selector` that exists at the time you run this code as that would be more efficient than using the `document` object, though `document` would work.

Comment: You will have to show us your HTML and what code it is conflicting with in order for us to know what to suggest.  This IS how you deal with dynamically added elements (using delegated event handling) OR you have to only install the event handler AFTER the element is added to the page.  Pick one of those two options.

Comment: jfriend00 has it exactly right... "tried but it's conflicting" isn't good enough. The only response to that is, "Well... then fix the conflict."

Comment: @Shashi - as you now have left things, your question is unanswerable.  We've told you how these problems are solved and you've told us it conflicts with your other code, but given us no more information about that conflict.  We are at an impasse and cannot help you any further until you either solve the conflict yourself or give us info about it so we can help you.  We may have to vote to close your question since there is no longer sufficient info to answer it further.  Which way do you want to go?

Comment: @jfriend. calm down dude. i just saw message. give me few mins and i will give html code too.

Answer (score 0):

In order to work jquery events properly on dynamically loaded elements you will need to attach events in this way.

```
$("#parent").on({
  mouseenter: function (e) {
    // perform mouse enter event
  },
  mouseleave: function (e) {
    // perform mouse leave event
 }
}, '#selector');
```

Where #Parent represent id of element where elements loaded dynamically.

Comment: where it conflict, you need to execute this code in function responsible for creating dynamic elements.